# error : unknown use of instruction mnemonic without a size suffix

Tags: gcc, x86-64, inline-assembly, att

Here the entire source code

```
void asmFunction() {
    unsigned char threshold[16];
    initArray(threshold, 75-128, 16);
    unsigned char counterC2[16];
    initArray(counterC2, 128, 16);
    unsigned char buffer[SIZE];

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(FILE_INPUT, "rb");
    FILE *foutput;
    foutput = fopen(FILE_OUTPUT_ASM, "wb");

    fread(buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), SIZE, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    __asm__(

            "mov $65536, %%edx\n"
            "mov %[thr], %%eax\n" // <--- this line
            "mov %[buf], %%ebx\n"
            "mov %[cc2], %%ecx\n"
            "movdqu (%%ecx), %%xmm2;\n"
            "movdqu (%%eax), %%xmm0;\n"
            "loop: movdqu (%%ebx), %%xmm1;\n"
            "psubb %%xmm2, %%xmm1;\n"
            "pcmpgtb %%xmm0, %%xmm1;\n"
            "movdqu %%xmm1, (%%ebx);\n"
            "add $16, %%ebx;\n"
            "sub $1, %%edx;\n"
            "mov $0, %%esi;\n"
            "cmp %%edx, %%esi;\n"
            "jnz loop;\n"
            : "=m" (buffer) // Output
            : [thr]"r" (threshold), [buf]"r" (buffer), [cc2]"r" (counterC2)
            : "xmm0", "eax", "ebx", "ecx"
        );

    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), SIZE, foutput);
    fclose(foutput);
}
```

But I get the following error and I don't understand why:

> unknown use of instruction mnemonic without a size suffix
>               "mov %[thr], %%eax\n"

Can someone help me?

Comment: I guess it wants `movl` there instead of just `mov`.

Comment: No.., still have the same problem

Comment: Which CPU is this for, more precisely? You should add the relevant CPU tag such as [tag:x86] or [tag:x86-64] to the question.

Comment: What's the type of `threshold`, and is this compiled as 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: Does compiling or assembling fail? Try to compile with the `-S` flag so the output file is an assembler file. If that succeeds, look how the affected instruction looks like in the assembler file (`%%` should be replaced by `%` and `%[thr]` should be replaced by something different).

Comment: Your code is incomplete.  Please post the complete code including all variable declarations.

Comment: It is compiled as 64-bit.

Comment: You are compiling as 64-bit code, but you tell the inline assembly to pass pointers to arrays via a register. The compiler will use 64-bit registers to pass pointers. So you will end up with instructions like `mov %%r??, %%eax` being generated where the `??` is any general purpose 64-bit register. You can't move a 64-bit register to a 32-bit one. Maybe you meant to do all your pointer related moves with a destination of RAX, RBX, RCX rather than EAX, EBX, ECX? As well anywhere a register is being used in a memory operand should use the 64-bit register, not the 32-bit register.

Comment: It would be in fact easier to suggest to change all references to a 32-bit register to a 64-bit one. That will also deal with the fact that some of your math operations are on the pointers as well. EDX and ESI should work as is since they aren't holding pointers and their values are known to be less than 32-bits.

Comment: Okay i see Thanks !!

Comment: Another bug:  `"=m"` means the operand is write-only, so the `fread()` would be a dead store.  Perhaps you mean `"+m"` to tell the compiler your function reads+writes the memory in `buffer[]`?

Answer (score 1):

try to replace `mov` by `movl`? 
It's a little difference between at&t and intel assemble language.

Comment: According to comments, the problem was actually conflicting operand-sizes: pointer operands are in 64-bit registers, and this clunky asm code used `mov` on them to copy them to hard-coded 32-bit registers instead of just asking the compiler for them in `"+r"` operands in the first place so the originals could be modified.